# Angular HighCharts Update series

Tags: angular, highcharts

Hello I am using `highcharts-angular` for my app. I have a problem about updating higchart series. It doesn't update correctly. I created [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b1zczv?file=src/app/app.component.ts) which you can see problem when click update.
in html part

```
 <highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="chartOptions" [(update)]="updateFromInput" style="width: calc(100% ); height: calc(100% - 67px); display: block;margin-top:15px;overflow: auto !important;">
</highcharts-chart>
```

in component part

```
 BarxFilter(model) {

        var series=this.groupBy(model.BAR.DATA,'GRUP','bar');
        console.log(series); 
        var categories=this.ArrNoDupe(model.BAR.DATA.map(x=>x.NAME)) 
        this.chartOptions = {
          chart: { backgroundColor: null, borderWidth: 0 },
          title: { text: '' }, credits: { enabled: false }, legend: { enabled: true }, tooltip: { hideDelay: 0, outside: true, shared: true },
          xAxis: { categories: categories },yAxis:{title:{enabled:false} },
          plotOptions: { column: { negativeColor: '#910000', borderColor: 'gray' } }, series: series
        };
        this.updateFromInput = true;
 
  }
```

How can I update chart correctly while series data changed ?

this is correct one
[image]

but when i click update gives below one which is wrong
[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems to work. What is the problem?

Comment: When you click update , If you see  second data, there is only one element. but graphs again shows 3 and write 1 and 2 as label name. It needs to be only one. And other one in second data only one year-month data sos there will be one bar only but  there are again a lot data @Troopers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [oneToOne option](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#options-details) to true before update : [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n2jrfi)